# CSS for tr:last-child { height: 100%; } or table height not working in puppeteer PDF

Tags: html, css, node.js, puppeteer

I have Node.js code like:

```
await page.setContent(html, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

const pdf = await page.pdf({
  format: 'A4',
  printBackground: true,
  margin: {
    top: '14mm', // default is 0, units: mm, cm, in, px
    right: '10mm',
    bottom: '35mm',
    left: '12mm'
  },
  displayHeaderFooter: true,
  headerTemplate: header,
  footerTemplate: footer
});
```

Where I have created a HTML that renders the height properly in Chrome:
[image: Webbrowser view]

However, when running this as `pdf` the TR height is ignored (red line):
[image]

I've tried a bunch of variations to get the table height and or TR's to set the full height of the page for the PDF but failed...

**Update 1:**

I've added the following to grab a screen shot of what  the page looks like by adding `await page.screenshot({path: '/tmp/full_img.png', fullPage: true});`

This gives me this view:
[image]

Here I can see that the page is rendered correctly in the "browser" but the "printed" PDF is wrong.

**Update 2:**

Also I added borders to the objects on the page and in the PDF I can see that the body (yellow) and the main (green) which is the tables container is fine and only the table (cyan) is not following the rules:

[image]

**Update 3:**

Now the "Print" option from Chrome in my local browser is consistent with what Puppeteer outputs:

[image]

Easier to test obviously... I will update the HTML below as well here: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/files/5747755/ut.html.txt

Comment: Can you try to set the container height to `90vh` with this css `@media print {.yourcontainer {height: 90vh}}` and check whether tr can stretch now?

Comment: Thanks, tried to use `vh` already on a bunch of places but seems it is still ignored. Any attempts to add a height to a table (or TR) is completely ignored by puppeteer it seems...

Comment: However, if I add a `div` in a `td` with this: `<tr><td><div style="height: 450px; position: relative;">&nbsp;</div></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>` it is expanding the height of the table in total.

Comment: Yes but it is static height. You need something dynamic here

Comment: Yes, it was mostly a reflection that the `div` height is honored by the puppeteer but it is ignored for table or TR...

Comment: I added a code as an answer that might fix your problem. Please try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after several hours digging through this I found that there are two issues here!

First, the code and the table need these CSS attributes:

```
//node.js
await page.emulateMediaType('screen'); //<-- important

//css
.itemstable {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0 0;
        -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 198mm !important;
        position: relative;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
```

Not sure if all of them are 100% needed but I won't touch them anymore! :)

**Second issue is that this seems to be some bug on Windows!**

I ran this html on Edge, Chrome and Vivaldi and all three browser on Windows gives me the above error, also running Puppeteer under Windows on Node.js!

I had my college test it on his Mac and he got the correct table/tr height in his PDF. I then tested the same code in WSL (Windows subsystem Linux) and in AWS Lambda (Node.js) and there it works fine with the above CSS changes!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add this to your css

```
@media print {
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it makes no difference... See update of my question as I can see that the "screen capture" is OK but the PDF is not.

Comment: Yes, that's why I targeted the `print` in css

Comment: Yeah, got it! Check the "Update 2" above. I added some borders which makes it easier to see the objects actual heights in the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with pupetteer to make an PDF invoice. I solved it with set ex: `height: 50vh` to the `<table>` tag (or css).
Then, I set a `<tr style="height:100%"><td></td></tr>` at the end (the same structure).

```html
<table style="height: 50vh">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          <th>4</th>
          <th>5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Content 1</td>
          <td>Content 2</td>
          <td>Content 3</td>
          <td>Content 4</td>
          <td>Content 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 100%">
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```